# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int when convert the binary to hex in Android

Tags: java, android, binary, hex

I trying to convert the the `binary` to `hex` and put into `Byte` in `Android`. But the App crash , and the error log is `E/AndroidRuntime(18032): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0D"`

The code is like the following :

```
String WorkStatus = "1101"
byte[] control = new byte[11];
control[10] = (byte) Byte.parseByte(String.format("%02X", Integer.parseInt(WorkStatus,2)));
```

It seems the **`0D`** is invalid int , what should I use for instead of **`Integer.parseInt`** ? or did I missing something ?

I want to do like the following:

```
control[10] = (byte) 0x0d;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rustam How to do the same as `control[10] = (byte) 0x0d;` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `byte` to be initialized with your `String` interpreted as binary, you could simply use:

```
String workStatus = "1101";
byte b = Byte.parseByte(workStatus, 2);
```

The `parseByte` static methods of `Byte` have the same signature as the two `Integer.parseInt` overloads: one with a single `String` and one with `String` and `int radix`.

The resulting `byte` will have value `13`.

You can represent it as `d` with `Integer.toHexString((int)b);` (`Byte` doesn't implement a `toHexString` method).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the method `Byte.parseByte(string)`, which parses a string in decimal notation. This doesn't work, because the string is not in decimal notation but in hexadecimal notation. You have to give a custom radix:

```
control[10] = Byte.parseByte(String.format(...), 16);
```

(Also, the return type of `Byte.parseByte` is a byte, so the cast is not necessary.)